# One-hot encoding with pd.get_dummies - show only columns with value 1 for chosen row

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

After one-hot encoding of my used cars dataset with 
`X = pd.get_dummies(data=X)` 
I need to see column which holds value of `1` for certain row. 
So if I select row like this:

```
 X.iloc[0,:]
```

I would get (I'm pasting only portion of the output):

```
model_106                         0
model_116                         0
model_118                         0
model_120                         0
model_124                         0
model_146                         0
model_147                         0
model_156                         0
model_159                         0
model_166                         0
model_190                         0
model_2                           0
model_206                         0
model_207                         0
model_208                         0
```

I need to find only columns which has value 1 for coresponding row. Other columns should be hidden.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [DataFrame.loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.index[0],df.iloc[0].eq(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this will helpful,lets take your dataframe as `df` and your required column names as `cols`

```
 df_= df[cols]
 result = df_.idxmax(axis=1).tolist()
```